# Connecting to apache atlas + hbase + solr setup with gremlin cli

Tags: solr, hbase, gremlin, janusgraph, apache-atlas

I am new to atlas and janusgraph, I have a local setup of atlas with hbase and solr as the backends with dummy data.
I would like to use gremlin cli + gremlin server and connect to the existing data in hbase. ie: view and traverse the dummy atlas metadata objects.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Run atlas server + hbase + solr - inserted dummy entities
2. Run gremlin server with the right configuration

   - I have set the `graph: { ConfigurationManagementGraph: ..}` to `janusgraph-hbase-solr.properties`
3. Run gremlin cli, connect with `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session` which connects the gremlin server just fine.
4. I do `graph = JanusGraphFactory.open(..../janusgraph-hbase-solr.properties)` and create `g = graph.traversal()`

I am able to create my own vertex and edges and list them, but not able to list anything related to atlas ie: entities etc.

What am I missing?
I want to connect to existing atlas setup and traverse the graph with gremlin cli.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To be able to access Atlas artifacts from gremlin cli you will have to add Atlas dependency jars to Janusgraph's lib directory.

You can get the jars from Atlas [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.atlas) or from your local build.

```
$ cp atlas-*  janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2/lib/
```

**list of JARs**

- atlas-common-1.1.0.jar
- atlas-graphdb-api-1.1.0.jar
- atlas-graphdb-common-1.1.0.jar
- atlas-graphdb-janus-1.1.0.jar
- atlas-intg-1.1.0.jar
- atlas-repository-1.1.0.jar

A sample query could be:

```
gremlin> :> g.V().has('__typeName','hive_table').count()
==>10
```

Comment: Nice. I setup jars, i start gremlin server with the right hbase and solr configs. I get this: `Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.solr.SolrIndex`

Comment: I did manage to connect. But its returning 0 while I have hive_table entities

Comment: @droaak, I suspect property value for "storage.hbase.table" is not in place in file "janusgraph-hbase-solr.properties", it should be "atlas_janus". Have you already set this property?

Comment: It is. I use atlas 2.0 and its 'apache_atlas_janus'. I verified using hbase shell as well. Actually now I get the same error but with `org.janusgraph.diskstorage.solr.Solr6Index`

Answer (score 2):

As [ThiagoAlvez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4446063/thiagoalvez) mentioned, [Atlas docker image](https://github.com/sburn/docker-apache-atlas) can be used since Tinknerpop Gremlin support is now build-in into it and can be easily used to play with Janusgraph, and Atlas artifacts using gremlin CLI:

1. Pull the [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sburn/apache-atlas):

```sh
docker pull sburn/apache-atlas
```

2. Start Apache Atlas in a container exposing Web-UI port 21000:

```sh
docker run -d \
    -p 21000:21000 \
    --name atlas \
    sburn/apache-atlas \
    /opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_start.py
```

3. Install gremlin-server and gremlin-console into the container by running included automation script:

```sh
docker exec -ti atlas /opt/gremlin/install-gremlin.sh
```

4. Start gremlin-server in the same container:

```sh
docker exec -d atlas /opt/gremlin/start-gremlin-server.sh
```

5. Finally, run gremlin-console interactively:

```sh
docker exec -ti atlas /opt/gremlin/run-gremlin-console.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when trying to connect to the Apache Atlas JanusGraph database (`org.janusgraph.diskstorage.solr.Solr6Index`).

I got it solved after moving the atlas jars to the JanusGraph lib folder as [anand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58554695/4446063) said and then configuring `janusgraph-hbase-solr.properties`.

These are the configurations that set on `janusgraph-hbase-solr.properties`:

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=localhost
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
index.search.backend=solr
index.search.solr.mode=http
index.search.solr.http-urls=http://localhost:9838/solr
index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=localhost:2181
index.search.solr.configset=_default
atlas.graph.storage.hbase.table=apache_atlas_janus
storage.hbase.table=apache_atlas_janus
```

I'm running Atlas using this docker image: https://github.com/sburn/docker-apache-atlas